# solr record grouping not working

Tags: solr

I want to apply group by on my solr document. I have tried

```
group:on&group.field=<field_name>
```

in my query. On using this I do not receive any record at all. 
In the solr doc, it is mentioned that the field on which I need to apply grouping must be indexed. That group field is already indexed in my case.
The hints and web have not helped me so far.
Solr Version: v6.2.0

Comment: I have also tried group:true option

Comment: Have you tried `group=true`? Any HTTP argument must have its key and value separated by `=`. What is the type of the field you're grouping on?

Comment: i think in solr the query is :(colon) delimited. There is typo error in the problem statement. I have tried group:true&group.field:asset_id. I have also tried your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, but it's not. In a _lucene_ query syntax, the field name would be separated with `:`. This is in the regular HTTP query params, not in a lucene query field. You turn on grouping by using `group=true` in the URL, as well as `group.field=fieldname`. It's also important that the field is _also be a string-based field, such as StrField or TextField_. What output are you actually getting?

Comment: I will try this suggestion. But do you have any idea how to pass request param in spring data solr